# Looping through ssh connections and directories

Tags: python, unix, ssh, putty, paramiko

I am using paramiko to remote into various hosts. 
I am able to run commands similar to that in a Putty shell.

I am working on a python script that will hopefully do this but I am struggling with a for loop to

Here is an example of my directories

```
   host01
      directory1
          file1
          file2
          file3
      directory2
          file1
          file2
          file3
   host02
      directory1
          file1
          file2
          file3
      directory2
          file1
          file2
          file3

import paramiko
ssh_client=paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh_client.connect(hostname='host01',username='loginid',password='password')

stdin,stdout,stderr=ssh_client.exec_command('''
    cd ..
    cd user/ze/log
    cd *05-07-2019*
    grep -c 1= file1 
    ''')
for line in stdout.readlines():
    print (line.strip())
for line in stderr.readlines():
    print (line.strip())
```

and so on..

Ultimately I want to grep each file within each directory on for a certain pattern.

I am struggling to understand how I can work variables in to the above.
Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: If all you need is `grep`, take a closer look at its flags (specifically, `-R` and these that produce machine-readable output) -- that might be a better option.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest creating a method to which you can pass values easily. Looping through it would depend on how you store the SSH connection details, I would advice a `list` of `dict`

the commands you pass to the SSH session strings so you can use `string.format()`. Docs for python3 [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format)

```py
import paramiko


def ssh_grep(ssh_hostname, ssh_username, ssh_password, username, date, grep_filter)
    ssh_client=paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh_client.connect(hostname=ssh_hostname,
                       username=ssh_username,
                       password=ssh_password)

    stdin, stdout, stderr=ssh_client.exec_command('''
        cd ..
        cd user/{username}/log
        cd *{date}*
        grep -c 1= {grep_filter}
        '''.format(username=username,
                   date=date,
                   grep_filter=grep_filter))
    for line in stdout.readlines():
        print (line.strip())
    for line in stderr.readlines():
        print (line.strip())


for item in ssh_list:
    ssh_grep(item['ssh_hostname'],
             item['ssh_username'],
             item['ssh_password'],
             item['username'],
             item['date'],
             item['grep_filter'])
```